# Select-box does not show a selected item when filtered in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am using angularjs to create two sets of dropdowns. The first dropdown contains a list of sports and the second dropdown contains a list of courts, where the selected sport can be played. So when the user selects eg. tennis in the first dropdown, then the courts where he/she can play tennis are shown. It looks like this: http://screencast.com/t/JFZ973IAILo7. Note that "Court 1" is selected as this is the first item in the dropdown.

But when I filter the dropdown containing courts, and the first court is not in the list anymore, no item is set as selected. Note that "Court 2" is not set as selected:
http://screencast.com/t/Fh1LvEgO

My code is as follows:
Dropdown with sports:

```
<select ng-model="selected.sport" ng-options="sport.name for sport in sports" >
</select>
```

Filtered dropdown with courts:

```
<select ng-model="selected.court" ng-options="court.name for court in courts  | filter:filterBySports" >
</select>
```

And my filter (using underscorejs):

```
 $scope.filterBySports=function(row) {
     if($scope.selected.sport!=undefined)
        return !!_.where(row.sports, {name:$scope.selected.sport.name}).length;
     else
         return true;
    };
```

So my question is, how do I set the first item as selected when filtering ?

Comment: please, post `sports` model.

Comment: To have something selected in a `<select>` you need to assign one of the items in `$scope.selected.court`. Try to assign the first item of the filtered courts to that scope. If you keep having problems I will put an example later.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding ng-selected="courts[0]" to my courts-select, but that didn't work. When looking at the FilterBySports-method, the $scope.selected.court is set to the first entry in the unfiltered court-select even when I change the sport to filter by to something which filters out the first entry in the unfiltered courts-select. So it seems I cannot set it in the filter-function either. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Take this template and please post your code there: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/882/ (undescore.js attached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the first item after filtered to `$scope.selected.court`. I suggest you to try $watch and $filter like this:

```
$scope.$watch("selected.sport",function(newValue,oldValue,scope){
        if (newValue){
            scope.filteredCourts = $filter('filter')(scope.courts,function(item){
                return item.sport == newValue.name;
            });

            if (scope.filteredCourts.length > 0){
                scope.selected.court = scope.filteredCourts[0];
            }
        }
    });
```

Your html now binds to `filteredCourts` instead:

```
<select ng-init="selected.court" ng-model="selected.court" 
         ng-options="court.name for court in filteredCourts">
</select>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ynrb7/1/)